# Trying to detect switch change using Verilog

Tags: verilog

**Intention**

I want to make a whackamole module using Verilog, to finish this, I would like to use 10 switches as the input signal for the user to hit the gopher, and if the signal occurs (switch status 0->1 or 1->0) and the corresponding LED lights up (only one LED will lights up in each cycle, and each cycle is 1 sec) , score counter plus 1.

**Part of my variable**

Below is some of my variable.

```
input [9:0]SW;                // 10 switch input as an array
output reg[9:0] LED;          // 10 LED output as an array
reg [5:0] score;              // the score counter, in the beginning initialize to 0
reg [4:0] clk;                // this clk is a 1 Hz clock
```

**Why can't I do this?**

After done this, the score counter just random jump to different value. What should I do to fix?

```
always@(SW[0])begin           // if switch 0 goes from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0
    if(LED[0])                // if LED lights up
    begin
    score=score+1;            // score counter +1
    end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "jumps to random value"? How do you observe that?

Comment: I use 7 segment display to show the value.

Comment: Did you debounce the switches?

Comment: No, how to debounce the switches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have a look at a digital glitch filter, I always use them for such use cases. Alternatively you could look at analog glitch filters. Usually I implement digital ones like this:

- I have a numeric parameter, eg. 0 .. 255
- I create a counter with the necessary number of bits (here eg. 8)
- When the input is high I increment the counter by 1 up to the parameter value
- When the input is low, I decrement the counter by 1 down to zero
- When the counter hits the parameter value, I suppose that the input is really high and its not just a glitch
- When the counter hits zero, I suppose that the input is really low and its not just a glitch

Comment: Also, you might want to "double-flop" the input.